# how to format Date object so that it gives me yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss

Tags: javascript, date

I have Date object and would like it formated.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date

This is the format I would like to be able to print

> yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss
>
> 2017-08-09 19:48:54

Whatever I try I can't get it to using console.log to print that. I allways get something like

```
Wed Aug 09 2017 19:48:54 GMT+0200 (Central Europe Daylight Time)
or
Wed, 09 Aug 2017 17:48:54 GMT
```

I do not need all that extra information embedded. If I create Date object and time is 19:53:00 and date is 2017-08-09 then I need just this 2017-08-98 19:53:00

How do I get that exactly? I need to send this to server just like that.

Comment: I recommend you look into using [momentjs](https://momentjs.com/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use [momentjs](//momentjs.com) library:

```
> moment().format('YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss')
< "2017-08-09 01:57:51"
```

You can also use moment with a javascript `Date` object:

```
const myDate = new Date()
moment(myDate).format('YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss')
```

Comment: Advising the use of an external library when something is available as standard isn't useful; loading the library is costly in developer and execution time.

Comment: This is one solution amongst other, that is viable and direct. And maybe OP want to do non-standard stuff anyway. But thanks to your comment, users may consider not using it, i'll update to _could_ :)

Comment: I have access to moment in my project, how do I make my date object a moment object so that I can format it as you suggest?

Comment: `moment(myDate)` should work out of the box

Comment: great that worked, how do I get it to use 24 hour instead of 12 hour. I got this val: Wed Aug 09 2017 20:09:51 GMT+0200 (Central Europe Daylight Time) converted to this: 2017-08-09 08:09:51 I would like  2017-08-09 20:09:51

Comment: Updated accordingly, check [their docs](http://momentjs.com/docs/) also, it's worth it. And consider accepting the answer if it's the one you used :)

Comment: Your answer should not rely on a library that is not in the OP or tagged. This is also a duplicate that has been asked many, many times before.

Answer (score 2):

This works fine :

```
function T(n) { return n<10?'0'+n:n; }
var d = new Date();
var formatted = d.getFullYear()+'-'+T(d.getMonth())+'-'+T(d.getDay())+' '+T(d.getHours())+':'+T(d.getMinutes())+':'+T(d.getSeconds());
console.log(formatted); // => 2017-07-03 19:08:30
```

Comment: your `T` function could concatenate the value of `n`, so you don't have to call getter twice :)

Comment: @UlysseBN Brilliant, thanks.

Comment: The T function also returns a string sometimes and number others, consider  making it always return a string: `return (n<10? '0' : '') + n`. ;-)

Answer (score 1):

```
let d = new Date();  // prints Wed Aug 09 2017 13:55:59 GMT-0400
d.toISOString();     // prints "2017-08-09T17:55:59.428Z"
// process the string to output in your desired format
```

Comment: Good answer, but it's worth checking for obvious duplicates first and just flagging the question instead.

Comment: its not a problem to get 2017-08-09T17:55:59.428Z but as you see that is 4 hours forward in time, I want 2017-08-09 13:55:59

Comment: @maxit I'm in GMT-4 and ISO8601 is always in GMT, so that's the result for me. To handle timezones, you'll need something more complicated like moment.js.

Comment: hi I am using moment, however I have on server implemented handling of timezones and I allow user of my application to pick the timezone he is in. So that is why I need to send to the server the simple time format of what user selected in the datetime picker component that is written in Vue, this component gives me this kind of format: 2017-08-09T17:55:59.428Z but that is problem since server takes that and applies its calculations and time ends up being wrong. Perhaps I should do all time zone calucations on client and not server? What is better approach from your experience?

Comment: I am using php on backend and I used this library https://github.com/camroncade/timezone to convert times to correct timezones when saving the time I do something like Timezone::convertToUTC($published_at, Auth::user()->timezone); and when reading from db Timezone::convertFromUTC($this->attributes['published_at'], $timezone, 'Y-m-d H:i'). This works fine for me. However would doing this on client be better choice or not?

Comment: I've never used PHP, so I'm not sure where it would be easier. If you have it implemented already, you might as well keep it though